# Relative path in play framework 2.3.6 in production environment

Tags: playframework-2.0, relative-path

In play framework 2.3.6, locally I can get the relative path of projects using `public static String projectPath = Play.application().path().getPath();` and store or retrieve files stored in public folders. But while working in production environment the relative path shows like `target/universal/stage/bin/<project-name>`. Now, I can't upload file or get files in public folder. Any Ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a static method and check if play is running in production. If yes, return the absolute path else return relative path. All the classes that needs the path will call this method.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple. You can't :)

Play is a stateless framework and it's against its ideology to store files to the file system. So you don't have a file system in PROD.

You have to store them to the DB or any other storage.

However you can access the files in the **/public** folder in this way:

```
play.Play.application().resourceAsStream("/public/someFile.gif");
```